Is this equation involving functions solvable? Just for fun, I found a problem and was wondering if I can solve the equation somehow.
Could be a very dumb question, if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions, then can we find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that they satisfy the following:
$$f(x) \cdot g(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
I saw a problem asking to solve for $x$ and $y$ where $x$ and $y$ are numbers: $xy = x + y$. I can then show that $x = \frac {y}{y-1}.$
Then I was wondering if instead we had two functions, can we solve such an equation? If yes/no, can you please elaborate?

Not following.  As you have remarked, for any given $f(x)$, assumed never to be $1$, we can take $g(x)=\frac {f(x)}{f(x)-1}$.  Were you looking for something else?

Thank you. Suppose I assume g(x) = x^2, then f(x) = g/g-1. But when I plot f(x).g(x) and f(x) + g(x), they don't overlap. Am I doing something wrong?

$g\times f = x^2\times \frac {x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac {x^4}{x^2-1}$  and $g+f=x^2+\frac {x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac {x^2(x^2-1)+x^2}{x^2-1}=\frac {x^4}{x^2-1}$.  So they match, except that when $x=\pm 1$, $f(x)$ is undefined.
